# Clear All Modal Popup data on data-dismissal in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple bootstrap modal popup on a single page (modal1,modal2,modal3), I want to clear or reset the form on closing each of the opened modal. I am using

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#modal1 form')[0].reset();
});
```

This works fine when I close the modal1 popup the above code resets the form , but I wanted to write common hidden code for all the modals in the application like

```
 $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.commonClass form')[0].reset();
});
```

Want this code to reset the form modal on close of any modal popup but it is not working as expected when using commonclass (which is in all modal popup) to clear the form. Is there a way to clear the form using commonClass

Comment: **$('.commonClass form')[0]** you are only resetting the first form with **[0]**, try to remove that.

Comment: get error $().reset is not a function when removed [0] @Toxnyc

Answer (score 0):

Looping through all the forms works for me

```
    $('.commonClass form').each(function() { this.reset() });
```